# Bake failed: Error: YAML parse error on ccgf-pipeline-jobs/templates/createDbWithUserV2.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, spinnaker

```
Bake failed: Error: YAML parse error on ccgf-pipeline-jobs/templates/createDbWithUserV2.yaml
Line 48 is - name: VAULT_BASE_PATH
```

my helm `createDbWithUserV2.yaml` is below

```
{{ if eq .Values.jobType "create-dbs-with-user-v2"}}
{{ $root := .Values }}
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: {{ printf "%s-%s-%s" .Values.jobType "custom-task" (.Values.uniqueId | default (randNumeric 25)) | trunc 60 }}{{randNumeric 2}}
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
  labels:
    customJobType: custom-pipeline-job
    customJobName: {{ printf "%s-%s" .Values.jobType "custom-task" }}
    customJobUniqueId: {{ .Values.uniqueId }}
    cloudtrust.rocks/servicename: {{ printf "%s-%s" .Values.jobType "custom-task" }}
    {{- if and (hasKey .Values "service") (hasKey .Values.service "standard") (hasKey .Values.service.standard "labels") }}
    {{- range $key, $val := .Values.service.standard.labels }}
    {{ $key }}: {{ $val }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- end }}
spec:
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: {{ .Values.ttlSecondsAfterFinished }}
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: 'false'
      labels:
        cloudtrust.rocks/servicename: {{ printf "%s-%s" .Values.jobType "custom-task" }}
        {{- if and (hasKey .Values "service") (hasKey .Values.service "standard") (hasKey .Values.service.standard "labels") }}
        {{- range $key, $val := .Values.service.standard.labels }}
        {{ $key }}: {{ $val }}
        {{- end }}
        {{- end }}
      namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
    spec:
      {{- include "customNodeSelector" . | nindent 6 }}
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: DB_HOST
              value: {{ .Values.dbHost }}
            - name: DB_PORT
              value: "3306"
            - name: DB_LIST
              value: {{ .Values.dbList }}
            - name: DB_PREFIX
              value: {{ .Values.dbPrefix }}
            - name: VAULT_ADDR
              value: {{ .Values.vaultAddr }}
            - name: VAULT_ROLE
              value: {{ .Values.vaultRole }}
            - name: VAULT_BASE_PATH
              value: {{ .Values.vaultBasePath }}
            - name: MASTER_USER_VAULT_PATH
              value: {{ .Values.masterUserVaultPath }}
            - name: DS_CONFIGS
              value: {{ .Values.dsConfigs | quote }}
            - name: DB_CONFIG
              value: {{ .Values.dbConfig | quote }}
            - name: CMD
              value: "create-dbs,create-dbs-user"
          image: {{ (eq .Values.overrideDockerImage "" ) | ternary ( printf "%s/%s" .Values.dockerRepo .Values.pipelineJobsDockerImage )  .Values.overrideDockerImage }}
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: {{ printf "%s-%s" .Values.jobType "custom-task" }}
          resources:
            limits: {}
            requests: {}
          tty: true
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: {{ .Values.imageSecrets }}

      restartPolicy: Never
      securityContext: {}
      serviceAccount: {{ .Values.serviceAccount }}
{{ end }}
```

Comment: fyi: you can define the image pull secrets in the serviceAccount so no need to define it again and again every resource

Comment: can you add the values.yaml to the question?